# Samba File Server shows already deleted users as directory owner / winbind name resolution

Tags: linux, samba, opensuse, winbind

I have on a **Samba File Server** (openSUSE Leap 15), a directory with subdirectorys in which some **should have no more owner**. User Name Resolution is going by winbind. I want to delete every dir with no owner.

The Problem is, that `ls -la` shows me, that some subdirectorys **still have a user as owner that doesnt exist anymore** in the AD. `wbinfo -u` doesnt shows me the deleted user and on the AD the user definetly doenst exist anymore too. Also getent passwd doesnt shows the users which ls -la shows as owner.

Things i have done already:

- Reboot
- net cache flush
- manually delete `winbindd_cache.tdb` and `winbindd_idmap.tdb`

Very strange, is there a other cache that would be not cleared by net cache flush?

PS: the nscd daemon is running too on the Samba File Server

Here the smb.conf for winbind config

```
[global]
    workgroup = domain
    realm = domain.DOMAIN
    netbios name = name
    security = ADS
    interfaces = 1.2.3.4 127.0.0.1/8
    bind interfaces only = yes

    log level = 1

    template shell = /bin/false

    vfs objects = acl_xattr
    map acl inherit = yes
    store dos attributes = yes

    registry shares = yes

    hide unreadable = yes
    #hide dot files = yes
    hide files = /$*/desktop.ini/RECYCLER/Thumbs.db/

    load printers = no
    printing = bsd
    printcap name = /dev/null
    disable spoolss = yes

    winbind enum users = yes
    winbind enum groups = yes
    winbind expand groups = 4
    username map = /etc/samba/samba_usermapping

    idmap config * : range = 2000 - 999999

    idmap config domain:backend = rid
    idmap config domain:range = 1000000 - 1999999
```

Answer (score 0):

File ownership is stored in the file-system. Simply removing a user from /etc/passwd or another remote user management does not remove the ownership in the file system. You just can't see the name for the UID and GID anymore.

If the user or group name still shows up with *getent* and you're running *nscd* caching *passwd* and *group* maps (check `/etc/nscd.conf`) then you should flush its caches for these maps:

```
nscd --invalidate=passwd
nscd --invalidate=group
```

A word of caution:

I'd recommend **not** to remove files found with `find -nouser` or `find -nogroup` automatically if there's even just a small chance that your remote user management might be unreachable.

Comment: Yes, thats exact what it should be. I want that the ownership is empty, so that i can list all orphan dirs with "find -nouser" and delete them.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your question before. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your tip, but unfortunately no change after this

Comment: I have added the smb.conf in the Question. Maybe this helps debug

Comment: You've tried exactly what? `nscd --invalidate=`?
`getent passwd foo` still shows a passwd entry for removed user?
What's in your nscd.conf?
Samba is just a wrapper on top of your POSIX user management and filesystem. So your smb.conf does not show the relevant stuff. It's at Linux level.

Comment: I have tried `nscd --invalidate=passwd` and `nscd --invalidate=group`.   `get ent passwd` shows NOT the deleted user. Only `ls` shows them.

Comment: If the user is not shown in _passwd_ map anymore _ls_ normally just shows the numeric UID. In your case _ls_ really still shows the **names**? Or just the numeric UID?

Comment: It shows really the name like this `domain\max.muste`